# Create Toggle Button Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use just ONE button to control Opening and Closing an Off-Canvas Menu. So I created a Button with `OpenButton` class which open menu, after clicking, I remove `OpenButton` class and add `CloseButton` class, These all work like a charm, But When I call `Click Event` on `CloseButton` It doesn't work, What is the problem ?
This is my code :

```
$('.OpenButton').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('CloseButton');
    $(this).removeClass('OpenButton');
});

$('.CloseButton').click(function() {
    alert('Close');
});
```

Comment: Use document on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're adding the class dynamically, you need to use event delegation to register the same with the event handler mechanism,

```
$(document).on('click', ".CloseButton", function() {
    alert('Close');       
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Then it opens the open menu as expected?

Comment: Yes, Thanks, I editted and added document.on for both of them and works like a charm ...

Comment: I want :), But StackOverFlow doesn't allow me to accept in 2 minutes, I'm waiting to terminate this rule ... :))), Again Thanks ...

Comment: Haha!.. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

That is because the click event is bound at runtime. Since `.CloseButton` does not exist when the code is executed, no click event will be bound to it. One solution is to use `$(document).on('click', '.CloseButton', function() {...})` to do that, but that is considered resource intensive and unnecessarily heavyhanded.

I would recommend that you do not change the class of the button instead. If you want to modify the style or appearance of the button when it's open/close, you can do it by adding classes instead of swapping classes, for example:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('is-open');
});
```

In this case, you can you also store the **state** of the button in jQuery's data object. That will abstract reading the state of an object from the DOM based on it's class:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
  
    // Store state
    if ($(this).data('is-open')) {
      $(this).data('is-open', false);
      alert('closing!');
    } else {
      $(this).data('is-open', true);
      alert('opening!');
    }
    
    // Toggle class
    $(this).toggleClass('is-open');
    $('.toggleTarget').toggleClass('is-hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.button.is-open {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button">Toggle</a>
<div class="toggleTarget is-hidden">I am content that is toggled.</div>
```